# Full Dependency Access using Background Service

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-8.0, mediatr

Given an ASP.NET Core API (dotnet8), using MediatR, i have a controller and want to archive the following:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAndPublish([FromBody] CreateAndPublishRequest request)
    {
       // create configuration (like metadata for a sth. and store to db)

       // do not wait for this, run it in a background task 
       await Mediator.Send(new CollectAndZipDataCommand());
       await Mediator.Send(new SendDownloadLinkPerMailCommand());

       return Ok();
    }
```

So the two Mediator commands should be executed, but take longer, so they can continue in the background and the controller will immediately return Ok().

Look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio and implement it like this

```
_taskQueue.QueueBackgroundWorkItemAsync(async (cancellationToken, serviceProvider) => {

var mediator = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<Mediator>();
await mediator.Send(new CollectAndZipDataCommand());
await mediator.Send(new SendDownloadLinkPerMailCommand());
});
```

allows me to successfully and correctly call Mediator, but the services of the CommandHandlers are null. I am quite sure it is the scope, but whatever I try, I cannot get a clean solution that resolves all the dependencies of my DI container in my background tasks.

[Mediator successfully resolved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33X5N.png)
but unfortunately, when CommandHandler ist called:

[nothing sucesfully injected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jY5cy.png)

Comment: "the services of the CommandHandlers are null" What does this mean?  "I am quite sure it is the scope". Why?  Why did you withhold any code and debugging information that would help someone understand those?

Comment: [tag:frodo_ff] Did you find any solution? I am facing similar issue in .net7 based jasontaylordev template based clean arch project.

Answer (score 2):

The problem might cause in scope, I suggest you try code like this.

```cs
public class PublishController : Controller
{
    private readonly BackgroundTaskQueue _backgroundTaskQueue;
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;

    public PublishController(BackgroundTaskQueue backgroundTaskQueue, IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
    {
        _backgroundTaskQueue = backgroundTaskQueue ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(backgroundTaskQueue));
        _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serviceScopeFactory));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult CreateAndPublish([FromBody] CreateAndPublishRequest request)
    {
        _backgroundTaskQueue.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(async token =>
        {
            using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
            {
                var mediator = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMediator>();
                await mediator.Send(new CollectAndZipDataCommand(), token);
                await mediator.Send(new SendDownloadLinkPerMailCommand(), token);
            }
        });

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

It works on me, you might need to define the queue.
For example:

```cs
public class BackgroundTaskQueue
{
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<Func<CancellationToken, Task>> _workItems = new ConcurrentQueue<Func<CancellationToken, Task>>();
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _signal = new SemaphoreSlim(0);

    public void QueueBackgroundWorkItem(Func<CancellationToken, Task> workItem)
    {
        if (workItem == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(workItem));
        }

        _workItems.Enqueue(workItem);
        _signal.Release();
    }

    public async Task<Func<CancellationToken, Task>> DequeueAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await _signal.WaitAsync(cancellationToken);
        _workItems.TryDequeue(out var workItem);

        return workItem;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan for your response. The issue is, that I receive the MediatR, but the CommandHandler which is called, has depencies like DbContext, IMailService and so on and they become not injected and are null.

Comment: have you register it in your program.cs

Comment: I am trying to something similar - add hostedservice for db command operations on a schedule with .net7 based  on **jasontaylordev** clean arch project. But it complaints that dbcontext cant be initialized in the requesthandler. Using latest mediatR nuget package which has changed last year, so tried above approach to get service via scope factory but it doesn't work in case of hosted service. Error => InvalidOperationException: Cannot consume scoped service 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[X.Infra.Persistence.XDbContext]' from singleton 'X.App.Common.Interfaces.XDbContext'.